# How do I add a text file to a pre-existing zip

Tags: linux-ubuntu, plugin-zip

I want to add a text file to a zip file using vim. I want to either add the file to my zip from local drive or create the file in the zip using vim.

Comment: (OTOH, see `man zip` and the part that starts "When given the name of an existing zip archive, zip will replace identically named entries in the zip archive (matching the relative names as stored in the archive) or add entries for new names.")

Answer (score 1):

The zip plugin documented at `:help zip` does not provide a way to modify zip files, only view and extract the contents.